# When should one set the constructor as constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am aware that c++11 allows for specifying expressions for compile-time rather than run-time by using constexpr.

I know that this could be done for the constructor of a class too.
However, this constructor has to initialize all the members of the class, in order to be used as a constexpr (in compile-time), and any functions that it calls should also be marked as constexpr.

But when would one set his constructor to a constexpr, and are there any other benefits apart from slight optimisation?

Would that mean that, if I CAN, I should ALWAYS set my constructor as constexpr?

Comment: A possible con could be that using a lot of `constexpr` objects increases compile time. And that's *not* saying it's never worth it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By making the constructor `constexpr`, you allow users to create `constexpr` objects, and use them in their own constant expressions. This makes the class friendlier in some circumstances; for example, when programming for an embedded system where you want to put data in read-only memory if possible.

So, from the point of view of making the class as flexible and generally useful as possible, you should do so if you can.

Comment: Can you only declare a constructor `constexpr` if the class members can be instantiated as `constexpr`?